# Failure 2616 Numeric overflow occurred during computation

Tags: teradata, numeric, teradata-sql-assistant

While trying to insert a record from flat file with length 18, the insert statement in bteq is working fine

```sql
INSERT INTO cust(online_customer)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN t1.site_id = 1002 THEN cast(t1.membership as DECIMAL(38,0))
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM trans t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cust1 t2 ON t1.membership = t2.membership AND t1.site_id = t2.site_id
;
```

but when the length increase to 19 im getting the below error

```
 *** Failure 2616 Numeric overflow occurred during computation.
                Statement# 1, Info =0   
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.
```

The `online_customer` is defined as `DECIMAL(38,0)` in `cust1` and `membership` is defined as `VARCHAR(40)` in both `trans` and `cust1`. The `cust` table has `online_customer VARCHAR(100)`.

Comment: Can you show the actual query and how the *flat file* is loaded?

Comment: 2677|793282394|4|13:55:21|11/22/2019|1|1|5931966436043|Kathy A|Garland|11 Woodlawn ave |Auburn|ME|US|04210|100 Mount Auburn Ave |Auburn|ME|US|04210|4571000022592272321.|1002|

Comment: Now this is completely different from your original question :-) You `cast(SUBSTR(t1.membership_nbr,9) as INTEGER)` and based on your example data this fails for `22592272321` which is way over the limit of an INTEGER.

Comment: case when  as integer is flowing into different column. I'm facing with the column vale 21, with CASE 
               WHEN t1.site_id = 1002 
               THEN t1.membership_nbr 
               END

Comment: If i reduce the value to 18 digits the code is working fine.

Comment: There's no `cast(t1.membership as DECIMAL(38,0))` in your query. When you run the Select only, does it work?

Comment: No, when i run only select aslo it throws error, so instead of decimal i used cast(cast(t1.membership_nbr) as float) as bigint), this modification has resolved the issue in teradata sql assist for the select query

Comment: @dnoeth CASE 
               WHEN t1.site_id = 1002 
               THEN CAST(CAST(t1.membership_nbr AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT)
               END worked fine in select in teradata sql assist, when i add the same case when in script it has faied with same number overflow error

Comment: When your `online_customer` is actually defined as `varchar(100)` the Insert adds no cast to a numeric value but a cast from numeric to string, strange. Please double check that the order of columns in your Select matches the order in your INSERT list and that the error is actually caused by that calculation

Comment: Your question is very unclear. But if you are trying to cast a 40 byte string into a decimal, that's not going to work. The max length for a decimal field is 38.

Comment: @dnoeth My mistake, when i initially tested the code in lower environment the code worked fine and while testing in preprod, the permanament table in TD was not in sync with lower environment, hence the insert was happening

Answer (score 0):

This could be coming from the `CAST` or the `INSERT`.  Try breaking apart the query and seeing which one causes the error.

In your query, you cast a `VARCHAR(40)` to `DECIMAL(38,0)` and then insert into a `VARCHAR(100)`.  Why not just insert `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` and use `TO_NUMBER()` to ensure valid numbers:

```sql
INSERT INTO cust(online_customer)
SELECT 
  CAST(
    CASE 
      WHEN t1.site_id = 1002 THEN TO_NUMBER(t1.membership) -- Ensure valid number
    END
    AS VARCHAR(100)
  )
FROM trans t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cust1 t2 ON t1.membership = t2.membership AND t1.site_id = t2.site_id
```

Comment: the falt file flow gets data as like  '4571000022592272321.', i have tired the above suggestion and failed again with same error

Comment: Hmm...are you required to validate that `t1.membership` is a valid numeric value?  If not, you can remove `TO_NUMBER()` and it should work.  Maybe you are hitting some system limits with the large numbers.